# Container-managed EntityManger is null on Injection

Tags: jpa, ejb

I'm nearly new to **JavaEE** (JRE7/JDK1.7.0) and startet my first (maven based) Project on **Eclipse** (Luna).

Applicationserver is **JBoss** EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) which I *updated* to JSF2.2 by adding *jsf-api-2.2.7.jar* and *jsf-impl-2.2.7.jar* and registering in *module.xml* - which works perfect, by the way.

The **problem**/question is, why can't I get the EntityManager from the container (AS) with **Injection**, with following code in my Project:

```
@Stateless
public class SCatRep {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    private ...
```

*In *persistence.xml* there is only one persistenceunit defined. So no further arguments are necessary ... in my opinion?!

On the other hand, when I try to get the EntityManager from container with a **lookup**, the EntityManager is present and everything works fine. I used this code (for testing):

```
@Stateless
@PersistenceContext(unitName="scha", name="persistence/em")
public class SCatRep {

    EntityManager em;

    public SCatRep() {
    try {
        Context ic = new InitialContext();
        em = (EntityManager) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/persistence/em");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

I read a lot forums and tutorials - because this behaviour is discussed a lot - but can't get a solution or answer. Hope somebody can help me and point me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I'm using EJB 3.1. And here is the *persistence.xml*:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="scha" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/scha_jndi</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <!-- SQL dialect -->
            <property name="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
            <property name="current_session_context_class" value="thread" />
            <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
            <property name="show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: post your persistence.xml as well

Comment: also, r u using EJB 3.0 or EJB 3.1?

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to access `em` field inside a constructor? `em` will be equal to `null` in time the constructor is run. If you have to initialize your Stateless bean you have to do it in method marked `@PostConstruct`

Comment: How are you getting your SCatRep instance?  If you are using it like any java class and just creating an instance, injection won't work.  It must be obtained from the container and be container managed for injection to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help.

I tried to access the EntityManager in constructor ... which is not possible, due to the initializationprocess.

Now I put the Initial loading (databaseaccess) in a @PostConstruct-annotated method and this works perfectly.